# Insert Image in HTML / PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I would like to add a profile image for this follow and unfollow system. How would I do this in this line?

I am thinking before the `<tr>` I would have a `<img src = ...>`

```
$t_rows .= '<tr><td>'.htmlspecialchars($v['NameFirst'].' '.$v['NameLast']).'</td><td>';
```

Comment: You can't have an `<img>` immediately before a `<tr>` - that would invalidate your table, you can't have content in between the rows. You could have another `<td>` e.g. `<td><img src=...></td>` or something. I don't know, it's unclear exactly what layout you currently have, or what layout you're aiming for. The question is a bit out of context.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to add a profile image based off of a PHP variable that has already been set, you could echo the HTML content.

```
<?php
$myVariable = "https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png";
echo '<img src="' . $myVariable . '" alt="Some Text..."/>';
?>
```

Comment: If I do this will it repeat before every name that is being displayed?

Comment: $friend_options = getUserForFriends();
    //output of the options is in a table
    echo '<table class = "users"><form action="friends.php" method="post">';
    echo $friend_options;
    echo '</form></table>';

Comment: You would need to put this code everywhere you want the image to be.